# Stack User Filter

Tags: script, chrome-extensions

This Chrome extension helps you keep track of questions by your favorite Stack Exchange users.

If you find that some users consistently post questions you enjoy answering, you may want to keep better track of their questions in the future. Simply click the name on user profile page to promote the user to *Gold status* (click again to demote).

The extension adds two tabs to the front page:

- *gold* for questions by Gold status users
- *pure gold* for their questions with *no answers*

Gold status users also have their names highlighted on the front page and in their profile.

The user list is kept in Chrome Storage and is synced between computers if sync is enabled. It is separate for each SE site (e.g., you may enjoy some user's math questions but not their programming questions.)

Available from [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-user-filter/fehpncjhoepfablpiekjehnckbgkbipe).

Plain JavaScript, CSS, Chrome Storage API, Stack Exchange API 2.2, [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/). [Source files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fl2pde4kx77dvuc/whitelist.zip).